# Sorting and loading data from Pandas to Redshift using to_sql

Tags: python, sorting, amazon-redshift, pandas-to-sql

I've built some tools that create front-end list boxes for users that reference dynamic Redshift tables. New items in the table, they appear automatically in the list.

I want to put the list in alphabetical order in the database so the dynamic list boxes will show the data in that order.

After downloading the list from an API, I attempt to sort the list alphabetically in a Pandas dataframe before uploading. This works perfectly:

`df.sort_values(['name'], inplace=True, ascending=True, kind='heapsort')`

But then when I try to upload to Redshift in that order, it loses the order while it uploads. The data appears in chunks of alphabetically ordered segments.

`db_conn = create_engine('<redshift connection>')`

`obj.to_sql('table_name', db_conn, index = False, if_exists = 'replace')`

Because of the way the third party tool (Alteryx) works, I need to have this data in alphabetical order in the database.

How can I modify `to_sql` to properly upload the data in order?

Comment: No sure, but it may be because of index. Try `df.sort_values(['name'], inplace=True, ascending=True, kind='heapsort').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: 1) If you load data to redshift this way it will be very slow (that may be ok for  you) 2) you cannot guarantee the order of results from a select without an order statement. I suggest you add a column on to your table to store the order in which you want them to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ingesting data into redshift, data gets distributed between slices on each node in your redshift cluster. 
My suggestion would be to create a sort key on a column which you need to be sorted. Once you have sort key on that column, you can run Vacuum command to get your data sorted.
Sorry! I cannot be of much help on Python/Pandas
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: This is a bit misleading and does not really answer the question. Also you have oversimplified the selection of sort key as "a column which you need to be sorted".

Comment: What I've done is sorted the data after pulling it from the db, so it's just another way around it. But thanks for reminding me to use sort keys.